# Is there a name for embedding of Lebesgue spaces $L^q(a,b) ⊂ L^p(a,b)$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, definition, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

> Let  $1 ≤ p ≤ q ≤ ∞$
>
> then
>
> $L^q(a,b) ⊂ L^p(a,b)$
>
> where $L^q(a,b), L^p(a,b)$ are Lebesgue spaces

Is there a name for this relationship? Is this the Sobolev embedding theorem?

Comment: $f(x) = 1/x$ is in $L^2$, but not in $L^1$.  Is that not a counterexample?

Comment: This is not the sobolev embedding theorem, since this type of theorem would be concerned with "trading smoothness for integrability". I am not sure if the inclusion you mention has a name. I would propose something like "the usual inclusion of $L^p$ spaces on finite measure spaces" or "an easy consequence of Jensen's inequality/the Hölder inequality" (whichever over you prefer).

Comment: @Titus: There are no counterexamples. The stated inclusion holds (if $a,b$ are finite).

Comment: Right you are.  Holder.  I'll remove the misguided comment.

Answer (score 1):

The embedding does not have a standard name. For example, no particular name is used in the article [Another Note on the Inclusion $L^p(μ)⊂L^q(μ)$](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322503) which is entirely about this fact.

Some of the ways to refer to it:

- since the Lebesgue spaces are nested...
- by the nested property of the Lebesgue spaces...
- the inclusion between Lebesgue spaces...
- by Jensen's inequality/Hölder's inequality (suggested by PhoemueX)